# On a large transport aircraft where exactly is the Forward pressure bulkhead?

Tags: aircraft-structures

Is the Forward pressure bulkhead in front of the pilots.. I.e when you lift the Radome for maintenance is that the Forward pressure bulkhead you can see? Some images or a diagram would be great.

Answer (score 10):

It's located  in the aircrafts radome (nose) where the weather radar is located. It's to keep the pressurized air from exiting the fuselage.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't always have to be there - on the A380 it's slightly further back than that and is a [complex structure which involves half of the front wheel well](https://img.directindustry.com/images_di/projects/images-g/airbus-a380-from-concept-to-reality-5956-8884127.jpg) - they build a further structure up to actually make the nose, but the pressure bulkhead is further aft.

Comment: @Moo that picture is strangely ominous, yet friendly...